# How to use Mock to handle [Function anonymous] in Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

This is my code:

```
export const requireValue = ({
  shouldDefault = false,
} = {}): ErrorRegistry.SingularErrorHandlerPair => ({
  handle: (v) => (v === "" ? "Value Required" : null),
  fix: shouldDefault
    ? () => ({ status: "default", wasFixed: false })
    : () => null,
});
```

Both `handle` and `fix` will return a function that returns either `null` or `{status: "default", wasFixed: false}`. How do I test against the function returns?

I went with this approach:

```
 it('returns an object with status "default" and wasFixed as false when shouldDefault is true', () => {
    const { fix } = requireValue({ shouldDefault: true });
    expect(fix).toEqual({ status: "default", wasFixed: false });
  });
```

Which gives the fail state of:

```
Expected: {"status": "default", "wasFixed": false}
Received: [Function anonymous]
```

Which I understand why it fails, my question is there a way to say something like `expect(fix) to be a function whose return equals { status: "default", wasFixed: false }`? Combing through Jest docs, it seems that mocks are supposed to be used for `[Function anonymous]` returns? Combing through the docs, I'm looking at mocks currently but don't quite understand how to use them correctly in this scenario (with me assuming that this is the purpose of mocks).

Comment: You don't expect that property to be an object, you expect it to be a function _returning_ an object. You don't need to mock anything, there are no collaborators here; you're testing a pure function.

Comment: Ahhhh okay so my issue is the use of toBe, changed it to toEqual and I'm getting somewhere. Now I'm slightly embarrassed I opened this stackoverflow question haha. Thank you @jonrsharpe!

Comment: Your example was _already_ using `toEqual`...